# Element is Not Allowed Here in Preference XML?

Tags: java, android, android-preferences

I am working in android project about preferences. I want to take Integer value in EditTextPreference. I search with this subject and I can use with this java class.

```
import androidx.preference.EditTextPreference;

public class IntegerEditTextPreference extends EditTextPreference {

    public IntegerEditTextPreference(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public IntegerEditTextPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public IntegerEditTextPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    protected String getPersistedString(String defaultReturnValue) {
        int defaultValue = -1;
        try {
            defaultValue = Integer.valueOf(defaultReturnValue);
        } catch(NumberFormatException e) {

        }

        return String.valueOf(getPersistedInt(defaultValue));
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean persistString(String value) {
        return persistInt(Integer.valueOf(value));
    }
}
```

But, I can't use in XML. When I use;

```
   <com.example.A.IntegerEditTextPreference
            android:defaultValue="80"
            android:inputType="numberPassword"
            android:key="Speed"
            android:persistent="false"
            android:numeric="integer"
            android:maxLength="3"
            android:title="Choose Speed" />
```

I take this error: "Element is Not Allowed Here". Now, I am searcing and they say I must use xml folder in drawable but it is Preference XML so I can't it. What can I do?

Edit: I add my xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <PreferenceCategory android:title="Notification">
        <SwitchPreference
            android:defaultValue="false"
            android:icon="@drawable/B"
            android:key="B"
            android:title="B" />
        <SwitchPreference
            android:defaultValue="false"
            android:icon="@drawable/A"
            android:key="A"
            android:title="A" />

       <com.example.A.IntegerEditTextPreference
            android:defaultValue="80"
            android:inputType="numberPassword"
            android:key="Speed"
            android:persistent="false"
            android:numeric="integer"
            android:maxLength="3"
            android:title="Choose Speed" />
    </PreferenceCategory>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

Comment: @whiterabbitj It is my package name.

Comment: @whiterabbitj Yes, just EdittexPrefences?

Comment: can you post the whole XML ?

Comment: @whiterabbitj Posted.

Comment: have you checked the java packed of `IntegerEditTextPreference`? show it on screenshot

Comment: Show the full error message for `Element is Not Allowed Here`

Comment: @Blundell it is "package com.example.A;"

Comment: try changing your packages to be all lowercase

Comment: @Blundell i try it but doesn't work. How can I add on Manifest in this java class?

Comment: restart IDE maybe ?

Comment: @whiterabbitj Doesn't work.

Comment: Try to replace PreferenceScreen with android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceScreen in the root tag of your preference @designanddevelop

Comment: layouts of PreferenceScreen's cant be in res/layout/ they have to be in res/xml/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can constraint on EditTextPreference. But, When you get this value, converting Integer or other values.

```
<EditTextPreference
    android:key="Speed"
    android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:summary="A"
    android:title="A" />
```